# ternary does not work on the jsf dataTable rowClasses

Tags: jsf

I am trying to use the ternary operator to conditionally put a class attribute on the tr element.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to get it to work.  Below is the code I used to test this with:

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{viewAliasesBean.deviceListTable}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <h:dataTable 
                value="#{item.device.phoneNumber.aliases}"
                rendered="#{not empty item.device.phoneNumber.aliases}"
                var="aliasItem" 
                rowClasses="#{empty aliasItem.name and not item.editMode ? 'OKRowClass': 'notOKRowClass'}">
                <h:column>
                    <h:inputText value="#{empty aliasItem.name and not item.editMode ? 'OKRowClass': 'notOKRowClass'}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:inputText value="#{aliasItem.name}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable> 
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Above produces the result below.  Notice that every tr element has the class attribute of "OKRowClass", which is incorrect base on what is displayed in column 1.
[image]

Is there no way to conditionally put a class attribute in the tr element? I am using myFaces 3.0.2 and would prefer to not use any other third party solutions, such as primeFaces, richFaces. . . for this.